# Texture paint colours not showing on model with normal maps

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I have baked normals on the model, and now wanting to texture paint, but the colours do not show, this may be due the painting on the same image as the normals?

[image]

Comment: Make sure to select the good Image Texture node in the Shader Editor, and also plug it into the Base Color of the Principled BSDF (not sure what is the node that is currently plugged). If it still doesn't work please pack your images and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to see your node setup in the attached screenshot, however it looks like you have connected an 'attribute' node to the color input on your Principled BSDF.

You should have an image texture plugged in to the color input. This should be a blank image on which we can paint colors. This should NOT be your baked normal map, which you seem to have correctly connected to the normal input on the Princlipled BSDF.

Please try these steps:

1. Create a new Image Texture node in your node tree.
2. Connect this Image Texture node directly to the Color input on the Principled BSDF
3. Use this Image Texture node to create a new, blank image. The resolution doesn't need to be too high, try 2048x2048 to begin with. The name of the image doesn't matter, use something like 'model_color'.
4. Go to Texture Painting, select the image you created in the node editor ('model_color'), and start painting. This will add color to your model, and will not affect the baked normal map. You can paint either on the image, or directly on the model itself.

Note: Please don't forget to use the Save All Images button on the Texture Painting screen each time you make a change to your 'model_color' image.

Comment: This worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: Don't mention it :) Would you mind accepting my answer using the tick mark on the left? An upvote would be much appreciated as well :)

Comment: Just done! Thank you for helping me understand blender hand painting more!